# Increase object property over an array, and delete if found in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Lets assume that I have an object defined by these properties :

```
interface HeaderObject {
  height: number;
  title: string;
  length: number;
}
```

I have an array that contains lots of HeaderObject.

My goal is for each element, if the element at a given index is equals to one found before this index, make its length increase by one and delete the object at the current index.

I must follow this rule:
If the object title is equals to the first one found before the index loop (in the following example, if i'm in index 6, the first one found is index 0) and heights are equals :
I must check if between the index found (0) and the current index (6), all objects height between these index follow the pattern (maxHeight - 1) for each element.

Here, length will not be updated because at height 2, before index 6, titles are not equals :

```
0: {height: 2, title: "Alpine Skiing", length: 1}
1: {height: 1, title: "2002", length: 1}
2: {height: 0, title: "Gold", length: 1}
3: {height: 2, title: "Archery", length: 1}
4: {height: 1, title: "2000", length: 1}
5: {height: 0, title: "Gold", length: 1}
6: {height: 2, title: "Alpine Skiing", length: 1}
```

But in this example:

```
0: {height: 0, title: "Country", length: 1}
1: {height: 0, title: "Athlete", length: 1}
2: {height: 2, title: "Alpine Skiing", length: 1}
3: {height: 1, title: "2002", length: 1}
4: {height: 0, title: "Gold", length: 1}
5: {height: 2, title: "Archery", length: 1}
6: {height: 1, title: "2000", length: 1}
7: {height: 0, title: "Gold", length: 1}
8: {height: 2, title: "Alpine Skiing", length: 1}
9: {height: 1, title: "2002", length: 1}
10: {height: 0, title: "Silver", length: 1}
11: {height: 2, title: "Alpine Skiing", length: 1}
12: {height: 1, title: "2006", length: 1}
13: {height: 0, title: "Gold", length: 1}
14: {height: 2, title: "Alpine Skiing", length: 1}
```

It must be :

```
0: {height: 0, title: "Country", length: 1}
1: {height: 0, title: "Athlete", length: 1}
2: {height: 2, title: "Alpine Skiing", length: 1}
3: {height: 1, title: "2002", length: 1}
4: {height: 0, title: "Gold", length: 1}
5: {height: 2, title: "Archery", length: 1}
6: {height: 1, title: "2000", length: 1}
7: {height: 0, title: "Gold", length: 1}
8: {height: 2, title: "Alpine Skiing", length: 3}
9: {height: 1, title: "2002", length: 1}
10: {height: 0, title: "Silver", length: 1}
11: {height: 1, title: "2006", length: 1}
12: {height: 0, title: "Gold", length: 1}
```

Thanks in advance for help. Here is where I am right now :

```
for (let j = maxHeight; j <= this.headers.length; j++) {

  for (let k = 1; k <= maxHeight + 1; k++) {
     if (typeof this.headers[j - k] !== 'undefined' && this.headers[j - k].title === this.headers[j].title) {
           this.headers[j - k].length++;
           this.headers.splice(j, 1);
           break;
      }
   }
}
```